# Загрузка Assembly

Tags: c#, assembly

В официальной документации показан пример

```
public static void Main()
{
        // Use the file name to load the assembly into the current
        // application domain.
        Assembly a = Assembly.Load("example");
        // Get the type to use.
        Type myType = a.GetType("Example");
        // Get the method to call.
        MethodInfo myMethod = myType.GetMethod("MethodA");
        // Create an instance.
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
        // Execute the method.
        myMethod.Invoke(obj, null);
}
```

Дело в том,что мне нужно загрузить dll посредством Assembly.Load, но я не знаю какие именно мне значения прописать вместо example,MethodA - объясните кто знает,пожалуйста.

Вот пример скрипта загружаемой dll

```
public class Uni : Facepunch.MonoBehaviour
{
     public void Start()
     {
          UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Test");
     }
}
```

Самое главное,чтобы dll работала как и стандартные Assembly из списка

Answer (score 2):

`"example"` — имя сборки (желательно полное, но можно и короткое). Об именах сборок смотрите [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/app-domains/assembly-names?view=netframework-4.7).

`"Example"` — полное имя типа, с пространством имён. У вас это будет что-то типа `MyLibrary.Uni`.

`"MethodA"` — имя публичного метода. В вашем случае это `"Start"`. Убедитесь, что метода нестатический и не требует аргументов.

Comment: большое спасибо - если бы мог поставил +rep

Comment: @Сергей: Пожалуйста! Надеюсь, что помогло.

Comment: а возможно ли их выгрузить?Я лучше вопрос задам отдельный вот он - ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/753138/Выгрузка-assembly